# WordPress Advanced Custom Fields Relationship Single Page

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I have a custom post type for "Clubs" and custom post type for "Events by Clubs". How can I get the name of the club on my single event page (not the while loop)?

I have searched and searched, but all I can find is to get it in a loop.

Below is the code for the single event page.

```
<?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

    <h1><?php the_title(); ?></h1>
    <section class="entry-content">     
    <ul>
        <li>Club Name: { get Club Name from Club post type relationship } </li>
        <li>Other detail: <?php the_field('blah_blah'); ?>
        <li>.....other details.....</li>
    </ul>
    <?php the_content(); ?>

    </section>
    <?php endwhile; endif; ?>
```

Comment: How your events are linked to your clubs, through a custom field?

Comment: It is linked through an advanced custom field relationship. So when I go to add an event (post type), I can choose a name from clubs (post type).

Answer (score 0):

You need to set up the postdata for the $club post object in order to access it:

```
<?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();

    $club = get_field('club_field_name');
    if($club):
      $post = $club;
      setup_postdata($post);
      $club_name = get_the_title();
      wp_reset_postdata();
    endif; ?>

  <h1><?php the_title(); ?></h1>
  <section class="entry-content">
    <ul>
      <li>Club Name: <?php echo $club_name; ?> </li>
      <li>Other detail: <?php the_field('blah_blah'); ?>
      <li>.....other details.....</li>
    </ul>
    <?php the_content(); ?>
  </section>
<?php endwhile; endif; ?>
```

A couple of points:

1. You must remember to call the `wp_reset_postdata();` function after you call `setup_postdata($post);` as otherwise other bits of the page won't work (as you're overriding the main page loop)
2. If you want to link to the club page you can move my piece of code to within the `<li>` tag and then use the_permalink(); as usual to output a link to the page (I've done it outside of your code to keep things clear).

Give me a shout if you're still stuck.

Comment: Sorry, it's taken a while for me to see this, but I will try that out and let you know how it goes. Thank you.